# String encryption/decryption error: argument not optional

Tags: excel, vba

I tried this code in a module. I get an error

> argument not optional

I'm trying to encrypt letters with letters without symbols and numbers and also to encrypt numbers with numbers without symbols and letters.

```vb
Public Function CleanEncryptSTR(MyString As String, MyPassword As String, Encrypt As Boolean) As String
'Encrypts strings chars contained in Allowedchars
'MyString = String to decrypt
'MyPassword = Password
'Encrypt True: Encrypy   False: Decrypt
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ASCToAdd As Integer
    Dim ThisChar As String
    Dim ThisASC As Integer
    Dim NewASC As Integer
    Dim MyStringEncrypted As String
    Dim AllowedChars As String

    AllowedChars = "&0123456789;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    If Len(MyPassword) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Len(MyString)
'            ThisASC = Asc(Mid(MyString, i, 1))
'            ThisASC = IntFromArray(Asc(Mid(MyString, i, 1)), MyVector())

            ThisChar = Mid(MyString, i, 1)
            ThisASC = InStr(AllowedChars, ThisChar)

            If ThisASC > 0 Then
                ASCToAdd = Asc(Mid(MyPassword, i Mod Len(MyPassword) + 1, 1))
                If Encrypt Then
                    NewASC = ThisASC + ASCToAdd
                Else
                    NewASC = ThisASC - ASCToAdd
                End If
                NewASC = NewASC Mod Len(AllowedChars)
                If NewASC <= 0 Then
                    NewASC = NewASC + Len(AllowedChars)
                End If

                MyStringEncrypted = MyStringEncrypted & Mid(AllowedChars, NewASC, 1)
            Else
                MyStringEncrypted = MyStringEncrypted & ThisChar
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        MyStringEncrypted = MyString
    End If

    CleanEncryptSTR = MyStringEncrypted

End Function
```

Comment: Which line did the error occured?

Comment: You should be using like `CleanEncryptSTR(MyString, MyPassword, Encrypt)` like the Function line at the top says. An argument not optional error means you haven't called the function with the variables it requires you to. Or you have edited wherever you got this from incorrectly and modified a variable in the wrong way. Which line gives you the error?

Comment: I have used a commandbutton1 and in there I have Call Module1.CleanEncryptSTR, thats where I get the error.

Comment: You have to provide the arguments, `MyString`, `MyPassword` and `Encrypt` and because it's a function, you have to assign a variable (or pass to other sub/function, whatever depending on what you need to do with the encrypted string) in order to store the outcome. e.g. `encryptedStr = CleanEncryptSTR("string","password", True)` https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html @TestingGroundz

Comment: In your command button, write `CleanEncruptSTR(` and you should get intellisense pop up when you open the bracket showing you the things you need to input.

Answer (score 0):

In your procedure of the command button call the function like below:

```
Public Sub YourButton_Click()

    Dim EncryptedString As String
    EncryptedString = CleanEncryptSTR("StringToEncrypt", "Password", True)

End Sub
```

The encrpyted string is now in the variable `EncryptedString`.

---

Just note that this kind of *"encryption"* is no real encryption and can **easily** be cracked. This might be useable for some fun or demonstration purpose but is not safe enough to be used for a real project.

Comment: I tried this but the button doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer *"Does not work"* is no useful error description. What happens? What does not work? What error do you get?